# Centos 7/NAGIOS/SNMP

Tags: centos

Estoy intentando configurar nagios en centos 7 pero a la hora de configurarlo las alertas me dice que estan todas de mis hosts correctas pero en Status information no me brinda información me indica el siguiente mensaje

```
(No output on stdout) stderr:
```

Esto tengo en el archivo commands.cfg

```
define command{
    command_name    snmp_1minute_load
    command_line    $USER1$/check_snmp -o .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.1 -H $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
}

define command{
    command_name    snmp_5minute_load
    command_line    $USER1$/check_snmp -o .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.2 -H $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
}

define command{
    command_name    snmp_15minute_load
    command_line    $USER1$/check_snmp -o .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.3 -H $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
}
```

Y esto en un archivo de mis hosts de windows llamado windows.cfg

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               web1.onemetric.com.au
    service_description     CPU 1 Minute Average
    check_command           snmp_1minute_load!-C public
}

define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               web1.onemetric.com.au
    service_description     CPU 5 Minute Average
    check_command           snmp_5minute_load!-C public
 }

 define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               web1.onemetric.com.au
    service_description     CPU 15 Minute Average
    check_command           snmp_15minute_load!-C public
 }
```

Comment: Creo que solo has copiado la primera línea del mensaje de error.

Comment: Es que solo me sale dicha línea